# Scrolling RadDataGrid with hidden columns throws error

Tags: uwp, telerik-grid, uwp-xaml

My DataGrid has hidden columns.  If I try to horizontally scroll to the end of the table before I "unhide" the columns, I get the following error.  Could someone please help?

{Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs}
    Exception: {System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.IndexStorage.ValueForIndex(Int32 index, Boolean approximate)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.CellsController`1.UpdateSlotWidth(Int32 cellSlot, Double cellWidth)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.Model.GridModel.Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.ITable.GenerateCellsForColumn(Int32 columnSlot, Double largestColumnElementWidth, IItemInfoNode columnDecorator)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.NodePool`2.GenerateCellsForLine(Int32 slot, Double largestLength, T lastElement)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.NodePool`2.GenerateContainer(IList`1 itemInfos)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.NodePool`2.MeasureForward(MeasureContext& context)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.NodePool`2.MeasureHorizontally(RadSize availableSize, Double offset, Int32 frozenElementsCount)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.NodePool`2.OnMeasure(RadSize availableSize, Double offset, Int32 frozenElementsCount, Double verticalBufferScale)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.Model.GridModel.MeasureHeaderRow(RadSize newAvailableSize)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.RadDataGrid.OnHeaderRowMeasure(RadSize newAvailableSize)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeaderPanel.Measure()
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.RadDataGrid.SetHorizontalOffset(Double physicalOffset, Boolean updateUI, Boolean updateScrollViewer)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.RadDataGrid.UpdateScrollOffsetOnRendering()
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.RadDataGrid.CompositionTarget_Rendering(Object sender, Object e)}
    Handled: false
    Message: "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.\r\n   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.IndexStorage.ValueForIndex(Int32 index, Boolean approximate)\r\n   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.CellsController`1.UpdateSlotWidth(Int32 cellSlot, Double cellWidth)\r\n   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.Model.GridModel.Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.ITable.GenerateCellsForColumn(Int32 columnSlot, Double largestColumnElementWidth, IItemInfoNode columnDecorator)\r\n   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid."
    Native View: To inspect the native object, enable native code debugging.
? e
{Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs}
    Exception: {System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.IndexStorage.ValueForIndex(Int32 index, Boolean approximate)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.CellsController`1.UpdateSlotWidth(Int32 cellSlot, Double cellWidth)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.Model.GridModel.Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.ITable.GenerateCellsForColumn(Int32 columnSlot, Double largestColumnElementWidth, IItemInfoNode columnDecorator)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.NodePool`2.GenerateCellsForLine(Int32 slot, Double largestLength, T lastElement)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.NodePool`2.GenerateContainer(IList`1 itemInfos)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.NodePool`2.MeasureForward(MeasureContext& context)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.NodePool`2.MeasureHorizontally(RadSize availableSize, Double offset, Int32 frozenElementsCount)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.NodePool`2.OnMeasure(RadSize availableSize, Double offset, Int32 frozenElementsCount, Double verticalBufferScale)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.Model.GridModel.MeasureHeaderRow(RadSize newAvailableSize)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.RadDataGrid.OnHeaderRowMeasure(RadSize newAvailableSize)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.Primitives.DataGridColumnHeaderPanel.Measure()
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.RadDataGrid.SetHorizontalOffset(Double physicalOffset, Boolean updateUI, Boolean updateScrollViewer)
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.RadDataGrid.UpdateScrollOffsetOnRendering()
   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.RadDataGrid.CompositionTarget_Rendering(Object sender, Object e)}
    Handled: false
    Message: "System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.\r\n   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.IndexStorage.ValueForIndex(Int32 index, Boolean approximate)\r\n   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.CellsController`1.UpdateSlotWidth(Int32 cellSlot, Double cellWidth)\r\n   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.Model.GridModel.Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid.ITable.GenerateCellsForColumn(Int32 columnSlot, Double largestColumnElementWidth, IItemInfoNode columnDecorator)\r\n   at Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid."

And here is the XAML:

```
<tg:RadDataGrid>
<tg:RadDataGrid.Columns>
    <tg:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="Number"
                                     Header="Number"
                                     SizeMode="Auto"/>
    <tg:DataGridTextColumn PropertyName="BaseText"
                                     Header="Base Text"
                                     SizeMode="Fixed"
                                     Width="300"
                           IsVisible="{Binding IsChecked,                      ElementName=ShowBaseCheckbox,Mode=TwoWay}">
    </tg:DataGridTextColumn>

</tg:RadDataGrid.Columns>
</tg:RadDataGrid>
```

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue . However,  from the exception info  *Index was outside the bounds of the array*, the data source may cause this issue,  could you share more detail about your data source？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telerik says this issue has been addressed in the latest update.  I have downloaded it from NuGet and it does seem to have fixed the problem.